# Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen error when running Bundle Install

Tags: ruby, selenium, rubygems, rbenv

When I run Bundle Install I get the following error:

```
mark$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using builder 3.2.2
Using ffi 1.9.14
Using gherkin 4.0.0
Using cucumber-wire 0.0.1
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using multi_test 0.1.2
Using rubyzip 1.2.0
Using websocket 1.2.3
Using bundler 1.11.2
Using childprocess 0.5.9
Using cucumber-core 1.5.0
Installing selenium-webdriver 2.53.4

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/CHANGES
Using cucumber 2.4.0
An error occurred while installing selenium-webdriver (2.53.4), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install selenium-webdriver -v '2.53.4'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

Any help how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so have you tried `gem install selenium-webdriver -v '2.53.4'`?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I have installed this gem successfully. The error still occurs though when I run 'Bundle Install'

Comment: with the same backtrace?

Comment: Yes exactly the same

Comment: show me `bundle show selenium-webdriver`

Comment: mark$ gem install selenium-webdriver -v '2.53.4'
Successfully installed selenium-webdriver-2.53.4
Parsing documentation for selenium-webdriver-2.53.4
Done installing documentation for selenium-webdriver after 2 seconds
1 gem installed

Comment: but then I get this whenI run Bundle show selenium-webdriver : Could not find selenium-webdriver-2.53.4 in any of the sources

Comment: seems like the gem is installed for another ruby version. what ruby version manager are you using?

Comment: Using rvm but not 100% how to use it or set it back

Comment: i dont think this is an isue with selenium. More likely it has to do with how to have bundler set up. Run `which bundler` - it should be using the version in `.rbenv/shims/`

Comment: I ran as you suggested and it came up as mark$ which bundler
/Users/mark/.rbenv/shims/bundler. What do I need to do now?

Comment: Use command

`sudo chown -R $user:$group /myfolder`